# using nHibernate to insert a new object to SQL Server gives error about identity insert not being turned off

Tags: nhibernate, insert

I have been pulling my hair out on this for a couple of hours at least now.

So I am using nhibernate to map my db to my code. In the DB I have table called "Product" which has a column called "ProductId" which is the primary key and also marked as an identity column in sql server 2012.

My class' mapping with the Id columned defined as:

`Id(x => x.ProductId, mapper => mapper.UnsavedValue(0))`;

However after creating a new Product object and trying to save it I get the following error and inner exception:

> {"could not execute batch command.[SQL: SQL not available]"}
>
> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Products'
>   when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

The exception is pretty clear and the product Id is set to 0. How do I tell nHibernate to not supply the Id column when creating a new object in the database?

Any help greatly appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generator used for the "ID" must be *native* (or *identity*), i.e. driven by DB engine. The mapping should be like this:

```
Id(x => x.ProductId
  , mapper =>
  {
    mapper.UnsavedValue(0)
    mapper.Generator(Generators.Native)
    ..
  });
```

See

- [Mapping - Id, NaturalId](http://notherdev.blogspot.cz/2012/02/mapping-by-code-id-naturalid.html)
- [5.1.4.1. generator](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator)
- [Using NHibernate mapping by code: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'DietUser' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279473/)